# Creating two html pages in SAPUI5 and executing one or the other depends on the situation

Tags: html, xml, view, sapui5, manifest

Currently I have my project running as welcomFile the index.html file. This file takes me to an authentication process. The case is that I need to access one of my views but without performing this authentication, that is, I don't want to go through this index.html. To do so, I created another html (index_new.html). Even if I run this last one it always redirects me to the index.html, I don't know if it has to do with how the neo-app.json file is configured. I tried to put in the index.html that if it arrived a parameter in the url to be directed to the index_new.html but without success, it says that the page does not exist. This is what I tried:

```
<script>
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    window.location.search = urlParams.toString();
    const con = urlParams.get('con');
    if (con !== ""){
        window.open("/index_new.html", "_self");
    }
 </script>
```

The only way I have managed to load the path I want is to run the program, it goes to the index.html and once it has loaded, I change the path to the index_new.html/viewthatIwanttoshow and it shows up. Is there any way to run the new index_new.html without having to run the old one?

I also think it's because of the manifest, because from the index_new.html I do it like this, just like in the index.html:

```
……
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap>
…
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"app.hello”: “./“}’
…
</script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <div data-sap-ui-component data-name="app.hello” data-id="container" data-settings='{"id" : “hello”}’ style="height: 100%"></div>
</body>
```

Maybe I should change the path here but I don't know which one or how to configure it in the manifest.json.

Maybe my question is not clear, if you have any questions please let me know.

My neo-app.json:

```
 "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
```

My manifest.json:

```
    "sap.app": {
        "id": “app.hello”,
        "type": "application",
```

Comment: Vandalism is not how you delete posts.

Answer (score 1):

I can't / don't want to give you a direct answer on your question. But I would like to mention to think about the concept you are going for.

I don't really understand why you want to load different index.html files. It's pretty far away from a best practice scenario - at least with the information I have out of your post.

When we are talking about authentication, mostly you save a token in cookies / browser storage. Then you can check if you are authenticated. If so, use the UI5 router. In every page you want to, you can check for valid authentication / authorization and redirect again to a login page, if you are not.

IMO you shouldn't use two different index.html sites.

I hope this help you to find another way to solve it.